# Can't set property in prepareForSegue:sender:

Tags: objective-c, ios, storyboard, segue

SOLUTION BELOW - Not really the problem I thought it was.

I'm adding data to the view controller that's being segued into, using prepareForSegue:sender:, but my problem is that if the data is set using a property then that property is not changed. I can, however, use a private variable of the destination view controller, set using a function built for that purpose.

Here's the code that works:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showLocationDetail"]) {
        CityGuideFlipsideViewController *flipside = [segue destinationViewController];
        CityGuideAnnotation *senderAnnotation = (CityGuideAnnotation *)sender;
        [flipside annotate:senderAnnotation]; // why?
    } 
}
```

It seems much more natural, though, to use `flipside.annotate = senderAnnotation` than `[flipside annotate:senderAnnotation]`.

Surely I must be doing something obvious here, but I can't spot it.

EDIT to give the fail case more clearly:

```
// CityGuideFlipsideViewController.h
@interface CityGuideFlipsideViewController : UIViewController {
    CityGuideAnnotation *annotation;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) CityGuideAnnotation *annotation;

// CityGuideFlipsideViewController.m
@synthesize annotation;
- (void)setAnnotation:(CityGuideAnnotation *)_annotation
{
    annotation = _annotation;
}

// CityGuideMainViewController.m (in prepareForSegue:sender)
CityGuideFlipsideViewController *flipside = [segue destinationViewController];
CityGuideAnnotation *senderAnnotation = (CityGuideAnnotation *)sender;
flipside.annotation = senderAnnotation;
```

On reaching the line assigning flipside.annotation as senderAnnotation the value of senderAnnotation is correct. flipside.annotation before assignment is nil. Following that line senderAnnotation is unchanged, flipside.annotation is unchanged.

BUT, reaching CityGuideFlipsideViewController viewDidLoad I have `NSLog(@"%@",annotation.title)` which spits out the correct value, even though the  debugger still shows me nil for annotation.

So I'm really not sure if I previously had some minor error of if all along I've been fooled by `annotation CityGuideAnnotation *   0x00000000` in the debugger.

Sorry about that, and thanks to those who helped.

Comment: Is it possible that before, you were not casting your sender correctly or at all.  I noticed you cast it to CityGuideAnnotation in the successful code but not in the example.

Comment: Please give the declaration and implementation of `annotate`. Properties are for setting ivars, and the equivalent setter method to `x.annotate = y` should be `[x setAnnotate:y]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was not in the code using a property. I was fooled by the debugger showing nil as the pointer. I'll be more careful to log values in the future.

See edit on question above for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If annotation is a private property on the destination vc, then the sender VC can't access it (apart from the annotate: method you set up). prepareForSegue doesn't give any special access to the destinationVC, in this case a private property. If you want to use dot notation you'll need to expose annotate as part of the public API.

I hope I understood your question properly :-)

Good luck,

Damien

Comment: Unfortunately it wasn't private. Also the compiler didn't throw an error, just left flipside.annotation unset.

Comment: Is it a UI outlet? Outlets are not hooked up in the destination vc during prepareForSegue.

Comment: Thanks for the help Damien, sorry I didn't figure out the debugger thing sooner.